# ERROR NOT_MARKET_MANAGED when testing expansion download

Tags: android, android-lvl, apk-expansion-files

I want to test expansion file down-loader, but application does not pass through LVL licence. It gives me `ERROR NOT_MARKET_MANAGED`

- My application is already published.
- I have drafted one app by changing version code and putting expansion file on Google play.
- In developer account, I added my email address to get test response and changed `response normally` to `LICENSED`.
- I installed drafted app in my real device and return error code 3 that is `ERROR NOT_MARKET_MANAGED`

Now what is missing?

**EDIT:** It is working now, I actually got `LICENCED` response after sometime. I think Google takes time to update it's server.

I am getting `XAPK file validation failed` and It stuck.

Comment: Solved all issue.. actually library validates downloaded file with hard coded version and file size.

Comment: Yes I can help you...

Comment: thanks i am trying to test the .obb file by manually adding it in /Android/obb/com.ss.aa/main.1.com.ss.aa.obb
it also creating the files folder automatically in Android/data/com.ss.aa/file
but files folder is empty
i get this error XPAK FILE validation failed, i have not uploaded the apk file in the market i am testing it locally

Comment: Can not test without uploading expansion file on Google play.. Google takes some time to update its server for first time, after that if you update expansion file on play you will get new expansion file instantly. remove validation of XAPK file.. It's not necessary. check folder where you have downloaded XAPK file(Android/obb/..xxx.obb).

Comment: But see here in the topic "Testing Your Expansion Files" http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing

Comment: It says we can test it, and also once extracted where the files will be stored ?

Comment: Yuap.. But you have to draft APK on google play with expansion file (Don't need to publish)